# How to store local logins plus OAuth Logins (FB and Google) using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

I'm planning to allow local logins, plus FB, and Google log ins. What is the best way to implement and store this? How do I structure my users?

Has anyone done this without using FOSUserBundle? Can anyone outline the basic steps and structure I should follow? Thanks.

Comment: If you want the basic steps then that's not what StackOverflow is about. You should try something and if you have a specific programming problem, that's when you should ask it on SO. You probably want to look into [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle). It allows FB and Google logins. Might be what you are looking for.

Comment: As @DipenShah said, read about HWIOAuthBundle, and how to implement custom user provider.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the pretty un-useful comments. The fault is mine, I should have worded my questions better. I am asking about 'norms' for how to structure the data to allow users from different sources. I'm familiar with custom user providers, and I'm looking at HWIOAuthBundle. But I'm a little uncertain about the overall structure for storing users from different sources. Thanks.